# MySQL statement counting nr of posts per topic not working

Tags: mysql

I'm building a forum using php, mysql and html. The system uses four tables (MESSAGES_CATEGORIES, MESSAGES_TOPICS, MESSAGES_POSTS, CRM) for saving the categories, topics, posts and customer contact details. The second sql statement below is supposed to retrieve a list of all topics for a particular category including the related firstname and lastname of the auto plus the number of posted messages per topic.

The part of the second statement for counting the number of posted messages per topic seems to go wrong, and I struggle to get the right syntax.

```
//this sql statement without counting works fine
$sqlquery0 = "SELECT MESSAGES_TOPICS.*, CRM.firstname,CRM.lastname "
        . "FROM MESSAGES_TOPICS INNER JOIN CRM "
        . "ON MESSAGES_TOPICS.topic_by=CRM.userid AND topic_cat = ".$val1." "
        . "ORDER BY MESSAGES_TOPICS.topic_date DESC";

//this sql statement with counting does not work
$sqlquery0 = "SELECT MESSAGES_TOPICS.*, CRM.firstname,CRM.lastname, COUNT(MESSAGES_POSTS.post_id) "
        . "FROM MESSAGES_TOPICS INNER JOIN CRM "
        . "ON MESSAGES_TOPICS.topic_by=CRM.userid AND topic_cat = ".$val1." "
            . "INNER JOIN MESSAGES_POSTS "
        . "ORDER BY MESSAGES_TOPICS.topic_date DESC";
```

Comment: You haven't defined what you mean by "*seems to go wrong*".  You haven't specified a predicate for joining `MESSAGES_POSTS`.  You're using an aggregate function without a `GROUP BY` clause, so MySQL will implicitly group all records (and select indeterminate values for the other columns).

Comment: You have no ON clause for your posts table - and you have no GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are saying that the second statement is syntactically incorrect, rather than it just produces the wrong results ....

I haven't used mySQL for a while, but the general rule for SQL is that to use an aggregate function like `count`, you also need to use the `Group By` clause.

Comment: As documented under [`GROUP BY` (Aggregate) Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html): "*If you use a group function in a statement containing no `GROUP BY` clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.*"  The query is perfectly valid, syntactically (provided that `$val1` is a valid SQL literal).

Comment: thnx both for your comments; I created another simple sql statement "$sqlquery1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MESSAGES_POSTS GROUP BY post_topic ";" which works. But now I struggle to merge that statement with the first in the code above...